# SQL Server SMO and PowerShell formatting

Tags: sql-server, functions, powershell, smo

I have probably been looking at this for too long to figure this out...

1. What is the easiest way I could get this exported to a CSV format?
2. Would it be better to dump this to a table in a database more
   easily? I will be running this from a central server that I do have
   an instance running.

The function below is for the purpose of pulling information about one or multiple databases of a SQL Server instance. So far I know this works on SQL 2005 and up.

I have used `Format-Table` but that ends up cutting off columns. I have used `Output-File` which can work but defaults to a list view which could be a pain to get into Excel. It also cuts off column data that exceeds a certain length.

**EDIT**: Purpose of this function is to run it against 100+ servers for gathering inventory of each instance.

PowerShell Function:

```
# Load SMO
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO')

function Get-DatabaseInfo ($server,$dbname)
{
    $srv = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' $server

    $db = $srv.Databases.Item($dbname)

    $DataFile = $db | Select -ExpandProperty FileGroups | Select -ExpandProperty Files
    $LogFile = $db | Select -ExpandProperty LogFiles
    $tables = $db | Select -ExpandProperty tables | ? {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}
    $indexes = $tables | Select -ExpandProperty Indexes |  ? {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $false}

    $srv.Databases.Item($dbname) | Select @{Label="*****************Database Name*****************";Expression={$_.Name}}

    Write-Host "Database information for $dbname" -ForegroundColor red    
    $db |
        Select  @{Label="DateCaptured";Expression={Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmm}},
            ID, Name, Owner, CreateDate, 
            CompatibilityLevel, RecoveryModel, 
            LastBackupDate, LastDifferentialBackupDate, LastLogBackupDate, LogReuseWaitStatus,
            ActiveConnections, 
            AutoClose, AutoShrink, 
            AutoCreateStatisticsEnabled, AutoUpdateStatisticsEnabled,
            Collation, 
            @{Label="DataSpaceUsage (KB)";Expression={$_.DataSpaceUsage}},
            @{Label="IndexSpaceUsage (KB)";Expression={$_.IndexSpaceUsage}},
            @{Label="SpaceAvailable (KB)";Expression={$_.SpaceAvailable}},
            @{Label="Size (MB)";Expression={$_.Size}},
            IsSQLCLREnabled,
            IsMirroringEnabled, PageVerify, ReplicationOptions

    Write-Host "Database File Level information for $dbname" -Foreground red
    $DataFile | Select  Name, Filename, Growth, GrowthType,
            @{Label="MaxSize (MB)";Expression={$value = $_.MaxSize; switch($value){-1 {"Unlimited"} default {"{0:N2}" -f($value/1024)}}}},
            @{Label="SizeAllocated (MB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.Size/1024)}},
            @{Label="UsedSpace (MB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.UsedSpace/1024)}},
            @{Label="Data % Full";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f(($_.UsedSpace/$_.Size) * 100)}},
            @{Label="Data Space Left (MB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f(($_.Size/1024)-($_.UsedSpace/1024))}},
            @{Label="Data % Available";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f((($_.Size/1024)-($_.UsedSpace/1024)) / ($_.Size/1024))}}

    $logfile | Select Name, Filename, Growth, GrowthType,
                @{Label="MaxSize (MB)";Expression={$value = $_.MaxSize; switch($value){-1 {"Unlimited"} default {"{0:N2}" -f($value)}}}},
                @{Label="SizeAllocated (MB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.Size/1024)}},
                @{Label="UsedSpace (MB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.UsedSpace/1024)}},
                @{Label="Log % Full";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f(($_.UsedSpace/$_.Size) * 100)}},
                @{Label="Log Space Left (MB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f(($_.Size/1024)-($_.UsedSpace/1024))}},
                @{Label="Log % Available";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f((($_.Size/1024)-($_.UsedSpace/1024)) / ($_.Size/1024))}}

    Write-Host "Table Information for $dbname" -ForegroundColor red
    $tables | Select @{Label="DateCaptured";Expression={Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmm}}, Name, RowCount, HasClusteredIndex | 
        Sort-Object RowCount -Descending

    Write-Host "Table Indexes Information for $dbname" -ForegroundColor Red
    $indexes | Select Parent, Name, IndexKeyType, IndexedColumns, FillFactor, SortInTempdb

}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you've tried [export-CSV](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx)?

Comment: I have. It only captures the first set for some reason. I would use inside the function but it does not have an append parameter.

Comment: See http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/export-csv-append/

Comment: Also [this Connect item implies it is fixed](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/525407/add-an-append-switch-to-export-csv), but in typical Microsoft fashion, doesn't explain when or where.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Apparently since each set is a different number of columns using export-csv with -append does not work. I noticed it was mentioned in the comments on Dmitry's blog post as well.

Comment: Well do you need all of the different sets in a single CSV file? To do what with?

Comment: I think the question probably should be "what are you going to do with this data"?

Comment: Sorry about that I thought I had put that info in the question, added it.

Comment: I can break up the function I guess, just thought it would be easier putting all the common things into a single function (database info, instance level information, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to PowerShell and SQL Server there is always different ways of doing or handling this scenario. I ended up just splitting them up as suggested by Aaron in the comments.

I don't want to delete this question so I am just answering it in this manner in case someone wants to use the scripts provided.

If a moderator feels that the question is better of removed, by all means go right ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar at a previous job and we ended up defining tables on my central server and granting permissions to my (monitored) sql sever agent service accounts to those tables.  Then we created a job and linked server on each monitored instance to the central server.